# Best practice for file transfers between two instances of a Google Compute Engine project

Tags: bash, scp, google-compute-engine

What is considered best practice for executing file transfers between two instances of a Google Compute Engine project?

**This is what I’m trying to accomplish:**

In my project currently, I have a main instance that is used to serve web pages and store data files. Upon receiving a user-initiated calculation request, a new instance is created using a saved image to perform this calculation. At the end of the calculation, I wish to copy the output files back to my main instance for storage.

**How I am going about this:**

A bash script is used to spin up a new instance along with metadata pertaining to the calculation request and a startup script that queries the metadata server and triggers the calculation in this newly created instance.

There is one final line in the startup script that runs a second bash script that attempts to initiate the file transfer and before deleting the instance.

The file transfer in this second bash script is performed using the `gcutil push` command. This second bash script is as follows:

```
#! /bin/bash
# Execute file transfer
gcutil --project=my_project push my_main_instance /home/username/file_to_be_transferred.txt /home/username/dir_on_main_instance
# Delete current instance
node=$(eval hostname)
echo Deleting instance: $node
gcutil deleteinstance --force --delete_boot_pd $node
```

**Problems encountered:**

While the new instance spun up fine and the calculation was able to successfully complete, the file transfer failed to proceed. The instance was, however, successfully deleted as per the second bash script.

I’m not sure what’s preventing the file transfer from executing. The odd thing here is that if I ssh into this new instance and manually run this second script, the file transfer would be successful and then the instance is deleted. The saved image contains ssh keys and when executing the `push` command, StrictHostKeyChecking is set to no.

Would be very grateful if anybody can point me in the right direction to resolve this. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

gcutil [push](https://github.com/cloudscaling/gcutil/blob/openstack/gcutil/gcutil/instance_cmds.py#L1118) doesn't do anything magical - it just sets up a scp commandline for you.  I recommend following a set of [passwordless ssh](http://hpc.ucla.edu/hoffman2/access/passwordless_ssh.php) instructions from the web using a set of credentials you make explicitly for the purpose of this copy, rather than your project-level ssh keys.

Comment: Charles, I've taken your advice and can now execute an `scp` without disabling StrictHostKeyChecking. However, the original issue with the file transfer not happening remains. The `scp` is set up correctly - it executes perfectly when I manually run the script (having ssh-ed into the instance) but it doesn't work when called by another script, i.e., the startup script.

Comment: Possibly you have something going on with your setup that requires a TTY for this command.  You would have when logged in but not when you are using it other times.  If you're using sudo in the script, check if you have [requiretty](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79960/how-to-disable-requiretty-for-a-single-command-in-sudoers) set in `/etc/sudoers`.  Otherwise, try adding some verbosity flags to the scp command and save the output to a logfile so you can see what exact error you are getting.

Comment: I've finally managed to get the transfer to work. What I was missing was to execute `scp` in the script with superuser permissions. In this case, it was also not necessary to disable requiretty. Very grateful to Charles for his comments.